# How to punctuate repeated thoughts/words when transcribing dialogues?

Tags: dialogue, punctuation

I'm transcribing a webinar for work and I need to get the punctuations right for this. How do I punctuate dialogue when the speaker repeats words in a row whilst wondering out loud? For example, in the following:

"I have read every single question and recent *hundreds thousands 
hundreds* of tips to help students use these questions effectively"

How do I go about punctuating the 'hundreds thousands hundreds' bit? I always find it really hard to punctuate spoken English, as it's obviously not always grammatically ideal anyway, but for someone who already has a poor grasp of grammar it can be really tough, especially considering how hard it is to find advice on dialogue grammar!

Comment: Do you want to do and accurate transcript? Often the language is tidied up and errors removed.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when people repeat things or misspeak in speeches, you can do something like this:

> "I have read every single question and recent hundreds, thousands - hundreds of tips to help students use these questions effectively."

Where you break it up with a little dash to show a pause in the speaker's thinking. You could also use periods (...) for this purpose.

Alternatively, you can use the time-honored newspaper trick and use [sic] to indicate the speaker misspoke.

> "I have read every single question and recent hundreds thousands hundreds [sic] of tips to help students use these questions effectively."

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much.

Comment: ive always wondered what [sic] meant